# Data reconciliation: What is the right way to approach this?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have two (big) group of numbers, let them be Group A and Group B

I want to divide each into smaller sub-groups and match sub groups from A with ones from group B based on sub-group sum

In another way, I'm trying get best sub-grouping from A numbers where the sum of each subgroup matches sum of a subgroup from B numbers (or differs in range)

it is like making balanced (by sum) sub groups from A and B

I'm sure there are ways away the brute force for this, and I'm sure there are some sort of algorithms talking around this.

Please list any algorithm (or a keyword) which I can search this problem with, my problem is that I don't know how to approach it right way.

Comment: This is an NP-hard problem. But how many groups do you want?  There are approaches that can work.

Comment: I've no constraint on number of groups,